# Sizes for iOS 8 backgrounds?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, iphone-6

So I have all my resources scaled up to @3x, but I don't know what size to scale up my background images to. I currently have them at 640x1136 for @2x, but this would mean 960x1704 for @3x which is going to look pixelated on a 1080x1920 device. What do I do for these background images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like iOS 7 assign @2x image,  iOS 8 will assign @3x image. 
To achieve these you have to add app icon, launch images & background images in image Asset.(creating new image asset..) so iOS will automatically assign appropriate image related to device or iOS.

check these links for more details:

http://aten.co/2014/09/12/designing-from-iphone-5-to-iphone-6-iphone-6-more-than-i-bargained-for/

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27

Hope this will help you..

Comment: This is wrong. You don't have to check in code. You can use an Xcode asset catalog.

Comment: Just a quick comment here that its slightly wrong. Just because a device has iOS 8 it won't assign @3x. Only the 6+ will use 3x, old devices will still use 2x even with ios8. But I understand what you are saying about the images not having to be linearly scaled. Thanks!

Comment: And yes as @Brager mentioned above you don't have to check using code, using an asset catalogue works fine.

Comment: but i have checked here in simulator with device iphone 5s with iOS 8 it assign @3x image..

Comment: using asset i have set app icon & launch icon but please explain me how to set background image using asset

Comment: are you using xib / storyboards? if so just create the image asset and enter its name in the image field

Comment: i have solved my issue with any device with iOS 8 assign 3x size image. now i am using asset to load images. now its working fine.. 2x for iphone 6 or lover & 3x for iphone 6 plus. thank you. now i got the image issue point..

Comment: @krishan711 Xcode assets catelog is not working for iphone 6. its taking 2x images with 640x980 size Rather than using 640x1136 iphone ratina image.

Comment: you can use in Image Asset Devices --> change to Device Specific.. then select Retina 4-Inch.. in that you can add image size 640x1136.